Events on XLAM Add-in not connected to Workbook
I made this test project, this is my standard module level code
 ' Declare a module-level variable to store the Application object
 Public App As Application

' Procedure to initialize the App variable:
Sub StartAppEvents()
    Set App = Application
End Sub

and this code on ThisWorkBook
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    StartAppEvents
End Sub

Private Sub App_WorkbookSheetChange(ByVal Wb As Workbook, ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
   MsgBox "App_WorksheetChange"
End Sub


Than I open new empty book and add this XLAM Add-in to new workbook

Nothing happens, Events in XLAM Add-in not connected to new Workbook.
Why? What I doing wrong?
UPD: If we adding WithEvents to App declaration - we need to move code to Class1 (Excel don't allow to use Withevents in standard modules). In this case we will receive another error:

What we need more? I see only two opportunity - add Public keyword to StartAppEvents declaration and change Instancing parameters from standard value (Private) to PublicNotCreatable. Both changing do not fix this error.

UPD2. Unfortunately idea from Tim Williams with New Events object don't working:


Your App declaration is missing the WithEvents keyword, and needs to be in an object code module (class, worksheet or ThisWorkbook for example) not a regular module.  It's all covered in the link I posted on your previous question.  See also: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/outlook/concepts/electronic-business-cards/using-events-with-automation#:~:text=You%20must%20use%20the%20WithEvents%20keyword%20to%20specify%20that%20the%20object%20variable%20will%20be%20used%20to%20respond%20to%20events%20triggered%20by%20the%20object.

Unfortunately no, not working recipe, I modify question, you can see what happens if I adding WithEvens keyword.

Your Class module is named "Class1" and not "AppEvents" - update your class module name to "AppEvents" and it should work.

@TimWilliams. And finally I have understanding relation between components. Very thanks, finally its working. I hope this solution also will very useful for other  programmers. Thanks again.

Public App As Application
should be
Public WithEvents App As Application
and it can't be in a regular code module: it needs to be in an object module such as a Class, Worksheet or maybe ThisWorkbook.
See for example: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/outlook/concepts/electronic-business-cards/using-events-with-automation#:~:text=You%20must%20use%20the%20WithEvents%20keyword%20to%20specify%20that%20the%20object%20variable%20will%20be%20used%20to%20respond%20to%20events%20triggered%20by%20the%20object.
For example this pops up a msgbox whenever I edit a sheet
ThisWorkbook:
Option Explicit

Private AppEvt As AppEvents

Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Set AppEvt = New AppEvents
    Set AppEvt.App = Application
End Sub

Class module (insert a new class module and change its name to AppEvents):
Option Explicit

Public WithEvents App As Excel.Application

'there's no "workbooksheetchange" event....
Private Sub App_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
    MsgBox "App_WorksheetChange"
End Sub

To make sure you're using a valid Application event, first select App from the left-hand drop-down at the top of the class module, then select an available event from the right-hand drop-down.

Its, don't working, sorry.

See my edits above.

I'm very sorry, but this is not working again. I have placed screen under label UPD2

Your Class module is named "Class1" and not "AppEvents" - update your class module name to "AppEvents" and it should work.

And finally I have understanding relation between components. Very thanks, finally its working. I hope this solution also will very useful for other programmers. Thanks again

Good to hear you got it working.
